# Angular2 how to handle value of date pipe is null

Tags: angular, angular2-template

I have template using date pipe like this

```
{{value | date: 'dd/MM/yyyy'}}
```

this `value` is `null`

How to handle this if my value null i got string `'object not match'`?

Answer (score 56, accepted):

```
{{ (value !== null) ? (value | date: 'dd/MM/yyyy') : "" }}
```

Comment: i got other error `Parser Error: Conditional expression (value !== null) ? value | date: 'dd/MM/yyyy' : '-' requires all 3 expressions at the end of the expression [
                    {{ (value !== null) ? value | date: 'dd/MM/yyyy' : '-'}}` @bharat

Comment: @Youngzie {{ (value !== null) ? (value | date: 'dd/MM/yyyy') : "" }}

Comment: There is a more succinct way to write this now.  See @Yurii-Bratchuk 's answer

Answer (score 19):

Checked with Angular 4.2.4

```
{{(value | date:'dd/MM/yyyy') || 'n/a' }}
```

Comment: While this doesn't interfere with the rendering process, it still litters the log with `Error: InvalidPipeArgument: 'Unable to convert "NaN" into a date' for pipe 'DatePipe'` messages.

Comment: still works with Angular 12.0.0 :)

Answer (score 7):

You can just add this:

```
{{value || '' | date: 'dd/MM/yyyy'}}
```

This should work like charm!

Here is the working [plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/LbqWh5PlW94UJ33f9Gz5?p=preview)

Comment: still error `Invalid argument '' for pipe 'DatePipe'` @Igor

Comment: What version of angular you are using?

Comment: Had a similar issue and it worked in my case :)

Comment: using angular 13, <span class="date-time">{{ column.cellValue(row) | date: "d MMM y HH:mm":"UTC" }}</span
><span *ngIf="column.cellValue(row) !== null" style="color: gray"> UTC</span>, if my timestamp retrieval fails, I want to print "Data Unavailable", how to create that error state condition? Any idea

Answer (score 4):

if your data is getting late and show in view invalidate date or anything then use this logic and set null first time.

```
@Pipe({
    name: 'displayDate'
})
export class DisplayDatePipe implements PipeTransform {
    transform(value): any {
        if (value !== null) {
            return moment(value).format(DateFormat.DD_MMM_YYYY);
        }
        return null;
    }
}
```

Comment: This would be better if it just deferred to the existing date pipe if the value wasn't null; there's no need to bring in the (now legacy) library Moment for a simple thing like formatting a date.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the nullish coalescing operator `??` since Angular 12 to keep it short:

`{{ (myDate | date:'mediumDate') ?? 'Nullish Date' }}`

(myDate must be null / undefined or a valid value which the date pipe can convert)

Answer (score 0):

Working with 5.2.0

`<h4> {{ (value | date : 'mediumDate') ? (value | date : 'mediumDate') : 'Present' }} </h4>`

Answer (score 0):

checked with Angular 8x

```
{{ (value !== "null") ? (value | date: 'dd/MM/yyyy') : "-" }}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using this simple method:

```
{{(value==null) ? value: value | date: 'dd/MM/yyyy'}}
```

Or, if you do not want to print null then you can put anything (N/A or Null or None) in below option under the quotes or you can also leave it as it is.

```
{{(value==null) ? "": value | date: 'dd/MM/yyyy'}}
```

Comment: Hi @Aashu, and welcome! Since this question already has an accepted answer, you should only submit a new answer if you can substantially improve on the existing answers. Your answer here doesn't appear to do that.

Answer (score -1):

In date pipe, If you are getting date in format of "dd/mm/yyyy" as "dd/00/yyyy"(where mm as null or 00) then use "dd/MM/yyyy"(MM should be capital) instead of "dd/mm/yyyy"

Comment: This question is about the error message "object not match" or similar when passing null as a value to the date pipe. If you have a different question which you'd like to answer, feel free to ask it (and answer it).